# Rounding to the second-nearest integer in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, math, rounding, integer-arithmetic

The `round` function in MATLAB can only round a number to its nearest integer. How can we round a number to its second-nearest integer?

For example, for 10.3, we get 11; for 10.6, we get 10.

Comment: What should `11.0` be rounded to?

Comment: Sorry, I have not think about this question. My problem is for a noninteger. Therefore, the code should check that the input should be a noninteger.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following logic

```
round2 = @(x) round( floor(x) + 1 - rem(x,1) );
```

The logic here is:

- Round down to the nearest integer with `floor(x)`
- Flip the fractional part (i.e. `0.6` becomes `0.4`) with `1-rem(x,1)`
- Add these together and round normally

A side effect of this is integers get "rounded" up to the next integer.

Test:

```
round2 = @(x) round( floor(x) + 1 - rem(x,1) );

a = [10.3, 10.6, 11];
round2(a)
% ans = [11, 10, 12]
```

Comment: Alternatively `round(2*floor(x) + 1 - x)`

Comment: @Stef Yep that just disguises my `rem(x,1)` as `floor(x)-x` I guess

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your suggestions.

I found a tricky way to solve this problem.

```
round2 = @(x) round(x) + sign(x-round(x));
```

The logic is:

1. Find the relationship between the input and its nearest integer (`-1` for `x<round(x)`; `1` for `x>round(x)`) with `sign(x-round(x))`.
2. Correct the result (`round(x)`) toward the direction of `x`.

Example

```
a = [-10.6, -10.4, 0, 10.4, 10.6];
round2(a)
% ans = [-10, -11, 0, 11, 10]
```

In this solution, the result of an integer is itself.

Comment: If that was your desired behaviour for integers you should edit your question to include that requirement